# Table column losing width in chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table

I found this really strange difference between Chrome and Firefox behavior.

I have a column set with `width: 25%` and an image header.
Without the image header both browsers behave in the same way, but with the image, the column loses its width on chrome. Check it here by clicking on the image:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked +img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table width='600' border='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center; background:white; color: #555; font-size:18px; font-weight:300; font-family: Roboto, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <img src="http://www.esandra.com/file/2012/09/slider-imagen.jpg">
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">APPROVED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:25%;">LOC</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:25%;">UK</td>
      <td>Simon</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:25%;">UK</td>
      <td>Niles</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">NOT APPROVED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:25%;">UK</td>
      <td>What happens if any name is thiiiiiis long</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>13203203212 seconds and 1215 minutes</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I think this is different from other questions because it is only happening when the image is there...

Here is a pen for you to try stuff: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/waPQZj?editors=110

Does someone know how to make it work in Chrome like it works in Firefox?

Edit: I forgot to mention that this is for a **newsletter** with variable content, that is why tables are a requirement (otherwise I wouldn't hurt myself by using them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `table-layout: fixed;` to your table. See [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tq3v7xcz/)

**Later edit:**

I got the the functionality of firefox in chrome as well by adding `max-width: 100%` to the image. See [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/a8u8nhsj/)

Comment: I saw your fiddle. I don't like how it works because in the end the rest of the content gets distributed very poorly